# Check if Translation is enabled in Apex

Tags: apex, translation, translation-workbench

How do I check if Translations is enabled in Apex? I have looked around but haven't found anything yet.

For more context:
I have created a custom datatable in LWC I have created custom outputfields to display values. When translations are enabled all the values are translated to let's say, French, other than picklist values. This would be fine if I was using the lightning-output-field which I can't for other reasons. Hence I have created a custom apex code that pulls the translated picklist values by doing a describe call.

By default, the page is displayed in English, I want to check if the translation is enabled and only then run custom apex code that pulls the translated picklist values.

Edit: I guess I can check for UserInfo.getLanguage()?

Comment: What is your use case? Can't you use labels and let the platform determine what it should display?

Comment: Edited my question and added more context @barrick

Comment: Consider using the LWC [i18n features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_i18n) along with LWC [picklist access](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values).